# SOLVED - Async function firing inside if-statement when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

### my isValid function was returning string so it was always true, while in the console i was getting true/false

I have function when the input-1 element changes, if the user input is valid it should fire an async function that fetches data and populates datalist for input-2.

Even tho `const validInput = isValid(input1);` return correct result, the async function always get executed

```
input1.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
    
function handleChange () {
    
    const validInput = isValid(input1); // correctly returns true/false
console.log(validInput)
    if(!validInput) {   
        hideInput(input2);
console.log('1',validInput)
    }
    else {
console.log('2',validInput)
        updateInput2datalist(); // gets executed either way
        displayInput(input2);
    }
};
async function updateInput2datalist () {
    let arr; 
    await getModelsAPI().then(response => arr = response);
    populateDatalist(input2Datalist, arr);            
}
```

from the console i get
`true 2 true`

`false 2 false`

Comment: I would say one of `correctly returns true/false` and `gets executed either way` may not be entirely true. Can it happen that `isValid()` is an `async` function?

Comment: isValid() only returns `return element.getAttribute('isvalid');`

Comment: Those true/false-s may be strings. A `"false"` string counts as `true` when used by an `if`. Try adding `typeof(validInput)` to the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reverse the `if` condition, as `updateInput2datalist` function will be executed on `validInput` equal `true` value.

```
if(validInput) {   
    hideInput(input2);
}
else {
    updateInput2datalist(); // gets executed either way
    displayInput(input2);
}
```